# Best defragmentation tool for Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, defragment

Windows Vista's built-in tool does not give any status of current state of defragmentation. And TuneUp is very heavy. Is there any other good defragmentation tool for Windows Vista?

**Edit:** I want a free tool (may be open source.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Defraggler](http://www.piriform.com/defraggler) from Piriform, the folk who gave us CCleaner, is my favourite. Free and portable.

[image]

Check out this [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5348638/five-best-disk-defragmenters) post for more options.

Comment: Do they do other software? So far Defraggler and CrapCleaner are the only two that I've found.

Comment: There's also Recuva (pretty good data recovery tool). And now Speccy, a system info and profiling tool. Still in beta and similar to plenty of other tools around.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.piriform.com/

Answer (score 3):

I like Auslogics defrag. It has a scheduler and an auto-defrag function.

http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag

Answer (score 2):

Sysinternals' **[Contig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx)**

[image]

If you're not comfortable with a command line utility, here's a graphical user interface for it:

**[PowerDefragmenter GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx)**

[image]

Very high defragmentation speed, efficiency and ease of use.

*Contig & PowerDefragmenter GUI are both freeware and portable, no installation is required.*

Answer (score 2):

Read '[The 2009 Defrag Shootout](http://donnedwards.openaccess.co.za/2007/06/great-defrag-shootout-all.html)', which should cover lots of the answers popping up here.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum PC magazine ran a [defrag utility performance comparison](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/the_disk_defrag_difference) a while back, and found that the built-in defragmenter is the most effective.  That is, defragging with Windows' built-in defragmenter netted slight performance gains, while defragging with the third-party utilities actually decreased performance slightly in most cases.  (Unfortunately, the article is now almost two years old, so things may have changed since then.)

In the end they did recommended [Auslogics Disk Defrag](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag) over the other third-party defrag utilities they tested, if you need a pretty graph and other features.